# Pycharm scratch files no interpreter set

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm having a strange issue in pycharm that I can't find any information on.

If I try to run a scratch file nothing happens, with no error produced. They used to work fine in this version (2016.3.2) but now if I check the run config as shown below, it shows project default as none even though its set and working for project files.

[image: No interpreter set]

If I change that to something valid, the scratch will run but I have to do it for every file.

I'm thinking this issue has something to do with renaming the project folder. I'm thinking I could probably solve the issue by deleting the pycharm project files and re opening the project but maybe there's a better solution.

**Update**

I was only able to solve this issue by removing my .idea folder and reopening the project. Not sure what caused it and have never been able to reproduce it.

Comment: can't reproduce in 2017.3.3

Comment: Second time I've gotten this problem now.. very annoying (removing .idea worked for me also)

Comment: @olejorgenb if you added your .idea folder to git you could check what the diff is to figure this out. I had mine gitignored before so couldn't check after I reopened the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue in the past as well, and I was also able to solve it by **deleting the .idea folder** and restarting PyCharm.

Also be careful about accidentally committing the *.idea* folder to your git repository (if you are using one), as this can lead to such problems when the same *.idea* folder gets used across different devices and software versions.

To avoid this, add the following entry to your `.gitignore` file:

```
# JetBrains IDEs
.idea
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, deleting the .idea folder is an option but not a good a solution as you also lose all of your other configurations. Hopefully at some point someone will get a diff to see what's causing the issue. Unfortunately? I haven't been able to reproduce since.

Comment: Configuration info shouldn't be committed to git anyways, it's bad practice. Suppose you set up a run configuration in your JetBrains IDE that sets environment variables to contain sensitive passwords or access tokens. When you commit your .idea folder, this information then gets committed to git and will be very hard to remove again.
That being said, it should be possible to share at least non-sensitive IDE settings through git, maybe this is possible through a gitignore whitelabel rule (that allows a single file inside .idea to be tracked in git).

Comment: I'm not talking about git, I'm talking about diffing a broken config with a working one to see what's actually causing the issue. Most people would rather not lose their "local" configuration.